# Implementing Distributed objects programming in CORBA to dowload file

Tags: java, corba, distributed-objects

When I run the Client, the following error appears on the console.

I am following the example from the following link --> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/rmi-corba-136641.html

Has anyone come across simillar problem. Please help.

**Client Console:**

```
FileClient Error: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.runtimeexception(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: FileTransferObj cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InvokeHandler
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.runtimeexception(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: FileTransferObj cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InvokeHandler
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at FileTransferApp._FileInterfaceStub.downloadFile(_FileInterfaceStub.java:20)
    at StartClient.main(StartClient.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Anyone who came across this problem . Surely must be following the example given in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/rmi-corba-136641.html .

Please the author of this program is runnign the program in an older version of JDK. So that was the reason that I came across this errors.

So please follow up with the solution in [CORBA example uses a different JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373385/corba-example-uses-a-different-jdk) .

This will help and also notice that in the class, where we implement the method. I have used `extends FileInterfacePOA` instead of `extends _FileInterfaceImplBase`